# Postgres and Javascript require to support more than 15 digits including decimal

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I need to store values in PostgreSQL database where 12 numbers and 6 decimal. According to PostgreSQL it provides numeric datatype. I created a field with `numeric(18,6)`, but when I am entering value, it is just accepting 15 digits values total.

For e.g.
If i try to store number 123456789123.123456, it truncates number and stores only 123456789123.123.

In JavaScript, when I am trying to parse a string of 18 digits including 6 decimals it returns only 17 digits, 12 numbers and 5 decimals.

For e.g.

```
var number = "123456789123.123456"
console.log(parseFloat(number));
```

it prints only 123456789123.12346

Is there any solution about this?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of the double-precision floating point data type and is not unique to JavaScript or Postgres. Postgres can use the same double-precision floating point type, or, as you have done, support an arbitrary precision number which is stored in a different format.

JavaScript only has one numeric data type: double-precision floating point.

- [Wikipedia - IEEE 754 Floating Point Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)

Keep in mind that this is a *precision* limitation, not "17 digits". You can successfully store `0.0000000000000003939393928293` or `8949493210129000000000000000000000000000`.

If you need to work with numbers of greater precision, you can use a library like bignumber.js. You lose the ability to use the simple operators, so `num3 = num1 + num2` becomes `num3 = num1.plus(num2)`, but it should do what you need.

- [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)